# How to parse XML string with bad characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a really simple example but it illustrates the problem.  The original XML has special characters and the original XML can't be changed.

This is an example of the XML: `<root><result value="3 < 5" /></root>`
And I need to replace the special characters in the data so it needs to look like this:

```
<root><result value="3 &lt; 5" /></root>
```

Everything I have tried makes the resulting XML look like this:

```
&lt;root&gt;&lt;result value="3 &lt; 5" /&gt;&lt;/root&gt;
```

I have tried this in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
--THIS WORKS (with no special characters)
declare @xml xml = '<root><result prop="works like a charm" /></root>'

select
R.N.value('@prop[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [prop]
from @xml.nodes('/root/result') as R(N)
GO

--THIS DOESN'T WORK
ERROR : XML parsing: line 1, character 24, well formed check: no '<' in attribute value
declare @xml xml = '<root><result value="3 < 5" /></root>'
GO

--THIS ALSO DOESN'T WORK - no errors, just no results
-- make XML a string initially
declare @xml_string varchar(max) = '<root><result value="3 < 5" /></root>'

--attempt to replace special characters in XML data
declare @xml xml
set @xml = ( select @xml_string for xml path(''))

--no results
select                               
R.N.value('@prop[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [prop]               
from @xml.nodes('/root/result') as R(N)  

--because the string looks like this: &lt;root&gt;&lt;result value="3 &lt; 5" /&gt;&lt;/root&gt;
select @xml
```

Comment: It's not an "XML string with bad characters", it simply not XML.  There's no general procedure to turn invalid XML into valid XML.  In particular cases you might be able to pre-process the string.

Comment: You are best off trying to process this in some kind of imperative language such as Python or C#, perhaps using Regex. You could for example search for matching `"` characters and try escaping everything within them. SQL Server is going to be really bad at this kind of thing

Comment: Honestly, regex ain't that great for this, either.